# Google Play Console rejecting app for using 'android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' even though it's not in the new version. How to avoid this?

Tags: google-play-console

I have an application written with React Native. After new API 33 Google Play removed start to not show for Android 13 my application in Google Play. I updated it and upload to Google Play console. However when I send it to *Release Overviewing*, they are rejecting my due to using `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but the problem is that I'm not using that permission.

There are many old testing that includes `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in my *Open testing* and *Close testing*. When I'm sending the the new version that is not includes `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, the old close testing version of the app, also going to *Release Overviewing*. It's possible that the rejection is about that old close testing.

- I want to ask all you guys, how can provide to not to send the old version of the app to *Release Overviewing* in order to not to get rejection.
- Or if there is any other solution, suggestions, please let know.

Uploading new application to Google Play Console.